# Can I keep my wlan powered on while sleeping?

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, wake-on-lan

I have Windows 10 Pro, a [Asus B85-PLUS/USB 3.1](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/B85PLUSUSB_31/) and a [ASUS PCE-AC68](https://www.asus.com/Networking/PCEAC68/). Is it somehow possible to keep the wlan-card on during sleep so that I can [WOL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN)?

Answer (score 0):

try to disable the powersaving feature(Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power ) of the network driver from the device manager.

Comment: Thanks, I did that but it still shuts down when the computer goes into sleep-mode.